# Warnings produced when loading a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When calling `rnn_model = keras.models.load_model('bin/rnn')`
after having trained a model and saved it with `model.save('bin/rnn')`

it produces a huge amount of warings in the console that i am not able to interpret:

```
2021-01-08 23:32:12.052179: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:12.072767: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:12.534962: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:13.515182: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:13.678562: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:13.707091: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:13.936798: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:14.196727: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:15.554499: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:15.581370: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:15.665304: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:15.689471: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:15.899045: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:16.416461: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:16.439738: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:16.598053: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:16.627368: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:18.063784: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:18.082790: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:18.869241: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:18.894552: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.063483: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.540079: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.569451: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.618969: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.649699: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.753987: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-01-08 23:32:20.777206: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
```

What do they mean and how should I handle them/prohibit them from occurring?

Comment: I have exactly the same question/issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

You might try adding recurrent dropout. It seemed to work for me when I had this issue. I suspect it has something to do with CudNN-optimized architecture having slightly different implementation.